# Как сделать появление Tutorial только один раз при первом запуске программы?

Tags: java, android

в приложении имеется `Tutorial`, как реализовать его появление только один раз при первом запуске программы. При этом хочу использовать SharedPreferences

Comment: `Tutorial tutorial = new Tutorial(); if (isFirstStart && !toSkipTutorial) tutorial.show();`

Comment: Создавайте туториал точно так же, как и все остальное в приложении. Гдениально, правда?

Comment: Что за заголовок. никакой связи с самим вопросом. первый вариант был уместнее

Comment: Есть отличная либа, которая на высшем уровне реализует функционал туториала по приложению - [MaterialShowcaseView](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) есть и [другие библиотеки](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972903/alternative-to-showcase-library-for-app-user-tutorials)

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли)))))

Comment: @pavlofff, а как ее установить?

Comment: Там есть инструкция подробная. Импортировать библиотеку в проект, добавив в `build.gradle` строки по инструкции

Comment: ок, спасибо сейчас вот смотрю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Организуйте с помощью `SharedPreferences`, привяжите `boolean`.
И сделайте где-нибудь в настройках `switcher` для включения подсказок.
При запуске проверяйте что-то вроде такого:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(TUTORIAL_INDEX, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean tutorial = sp.getBoolean("tutorial", false);
if (!tutorial) {
    // выводите tutorial
    Editor e = sp.edit();
    e.putBoolean("tutorial", true);
    e.commit();
}
```

Comment: суть не только  SharedPreferences это я знаю, как лучше просто это реализовать что использовать, фрагменты или новые активити, как реализовать Tutorial более грамотно

Comment: Ну вопрос значит не правильно задан, ответ ещё проще. 
Как хочешь, на сколько фантазии хватит хоть видео впихивай. Я пару раз делал, очень классно получается, когда ты показываешь именно такую разметку, какая у тебя имеется, затемняешь экран, кроме нужного элемента, этот элемент единственный активный, лочишь всё остальное и пока пользователь не нажмет этот элемент, след окна не будет. всё просто. Эффект на затемнение сделай будет смотреться отлично. Да, рекомендую через Fragments...

Comment: воот точно а как все это делать, как сделать эффект затемнения, подскажи пожалуйста

Comment: это другой вопрос, тут по правилу надо в отдельный запихать его, кстати оформи его красиво, я уверен будет классный вопрос, поможешь людям, а я с удовольствием отвечу.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei этот вопрос вообще очень пространный, размытый.

Comment: ок, сейчас задам )

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, я добавил вопрос